Report - Group Field Section: Dynamic Filtering of Geopoints
Situation: I am working on a report that uses a geopoint layer. The underlying table has columns for id, cat_name, and points in the format point Z (...). Each cat_name has multiple points (rows of many points) associated with it. For the report, I created a source table with distinct cat_name values and a column that includes all the associated points as multipoint Z(...). This lets me display one page per cat_name in the report (dispite many points/rows in the geopoints layer), zoomed to the area of the points.
Goal: I want to create a report where each page is focused on a specific cat_name and ONLY displays the points associated with that cat_name (zoomed in to the relevant area).
Problem: While generating the report, some of the points are overlapping because several cat_name values share the same area. Currently, the report is showing all points in the same area for multiple cat_name values, which causes overlap. I need a way to ensure that only the points for one cat_name are shown on each page.
Anyone can help me with that?
I am using QGIS 3.4

You simply need to add and cat_name = 'your-current-cat_name' in the query that forms your report (replacing your-current-cat_name with the proper value).
